# Unit of Work with Dependency Injection

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ninject, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I'm building a relatively simple webapp in ASP.NET MVC 4, using Entity Framework to talk to MS SQL Server. There's lots of scope to expand the application in future, so I'm aiming for a pattern that maximises reusability and adaptability in the code, to save work later on. The idea is:

- Unit of Work pattern, to save problems with the database by only committing changes at the end of each set of actions.
- Generic repository using `BaseRepository<T>` because the repositories will be mostly the same; the odd exception can extend and add its additional methods.
- Dependency injection to bind those repositories to the `IRepository<T>` that the controllers will be using, so that I can switch data storage methods and such with minimal fuss (not just for best practice; there is a real chance of this happening). I'm using Ninject for this.

I haven't really attempted something like this from scratch before, so I've been reading up and I think I've got myself muddled somewhere. So far, I have an interface `IRepository<T>` which is implemented by `BaseRepository<T>`, which contains an instance of the `DataContext` which is passed into its constructor. This interface has methods for Add, Update, Delete, and various types of Get (single by ID, single by predicate, group by predicate, all). The only repository that doesn't fit this interface (so far) is the Users repository, which adds `User Login(string username, string password)` to allow login (the implementation of which handles all the salting, hashing, checking etc).

From what I've read, I now need a `UnitOfWork` class that contains instances of all the repositories. This unit of work will expose the repositories, as well as a SaveChanges() method. When I want to manipulate data, I instantiate a unit of work, access the repositories on it (which are instantiated as needed), and then save. If anything fails, nothing changes in the database because it won't reach the single save at the end. This is all fine. My problem is that all the examples I can find seem to do one of two things:

- Some pass a data context into the unit of work, from which they retrieve the various repositories. This negates the point of DI by having my Entity-Framework-specific `DbContext` (or a class inherited from it) in my unit of work.
- Some call a Get method to request a repository, which is the service locator pattern, which is at least unpopular, if not an antipattern, and either way I'd like to avoid  it here.

Do I need to create an interface for my data source and inject that into the unit of work as well? I can't find any documentation on this that's clear and/or complete enough to explain.

**EDIT**

I think I've been overcomplicating it; I'm now folding my repository and unit of work into one - my repository is entirely generic so this just gives me a handful of generic methods (Add, Remove, Update, and a few kinds of Get) plus a SaveChanges method. This gives me a worker class interface; I can then have a factory class that provides instances of it (also interfaced). If I also have this worker implement `IDisposable` then I can use it in a scoped block. So now my controllers can do something like this:

```
using (var worker = DataAccess.BeginTransaction())
{
    Product item = worker.Get<Product>(p => p.ID == prodName);
    //stuff...
    worker.SaveChanges();
}
```

If something goes wrong before the `SaveChanges()`, then all changes are discarded when it exits the scope block and the worker is disposed. I can use dependency injection to provide concrete implementations to the `DataAccess` field, which is passed into the base controller constructor. Business logic is all in the controller and works with `IQueryable` objects, so I can switch out the `DataAccess` provider object for anything I like as long as it implements the `IRepository` interface; there's nothing specific to Entity Framework anywhere.

So, any thoughts on this implementation? Is this on the right track?

Comment: I am tempted to point you to [YAGNI principle](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?YouArentGonnaNeedIt). Nothing wrong in pursuing the question academically, but I feel what you foresee is subject to a wide spectrum of changes, and you might see yourself having to change your design a lot. Worse is you may be stuck with it.

Comment: I appreciate that, and normally I'd agree, but I know that this is likely to be needed. I'm building to deploy to a server with MSSQL Server, but I have other people who also want versions and at least one of them won't have access to that. There's no single system common to all the places this is going to be deployed to. If I know I can just write a new data access layer implementation and switch out a handful of bindings to deploy to somewhere else, it'll save me a tone of work later. That, and I want to learn how to do it properly, and this is a good opportunity.

Comment: Completely with you, I haven't the faintest idea on what your setup is, just that your description seems to suggest you are looking to build something future-proof(which I am not a big fan of), and hence the reference to YAGNI. But with this clarification, I guess you are at a point where you might as well design something generic.

Comment: "Future-proof" is a dangerous term; the future is vague and unpredictable. This isn't so much future-proofing as it is designing Phase 1 to not cause more work in Phase 2.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520729/ninject-unitofwork-confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to have `UnitOfWork` or a `UnitOfWorkFactory` injected into the repositories, that way I need not bother it everytime a new reposiory is added. Responsibility of UnitOfWork would be to just manage the transaction.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882510.aspx) is an example of what I mean.